# Trac API won't send email

Tags: python, trac

The Trac web application sends out emails perfectly. I even configured the Trac Html Notification plugin and that works too.

I want to use the API to update tickets and have them send out the notification as well and it is not working.
I am doing something like this

```
from trac.core import *
from trac.env import Environment
from trac.ticket.model import Ticket

env = Environment('E:\Trac/project')

tkt = Ticket(env, 383)
tkt['status'] = 'assigned'
tkt.save_changes()
```

Or

```
from trac.core import *
from trac.env import Environment
from trac.ticket.model import Ticket

env = Environment('E:\Trac/project')

summary =  "Test New Ticket"
description = 'Testing new ticket'

tkt = Ticket(env)
tkt['reporter'] = 'jorozco'
tkt['owner'] = 'jorozco'
tkt['summary'] = summary
tkt['description'] = description
tkt['priority'] = 'Top'
tkt['task'] = '33'
tkt['status'] = 'new'
tkt.insert()
```

I am using Trac version 1.5.1 on Windows.

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notifications aren't sent by changing a `Ticket` model object. Rather, you have to create a `TicketChangeEvent` and pass it to `NotificationSystem.notify`. See [here](https://trac.edgewall.org/browser/tags/trac-1.5.1/trac/ticket/web_ui.py?marks=1331,1341-1342,1344#L1326).

In the future we may try to implement notification through `ITicketChangeListener` so that it's invoked on changes to a ticket object, but it requires some redesign. See [#13029](https://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/13029).